# how to resend mobile otp

Tags: javascript, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication

using firebase OTP notification. cant reuse

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
```

for resend otp after timer is complete.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/phone-invisible.html

i am using this library.

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', { 

});
```

I want to reuse this after "RESEND" click, but its showing error :

> Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are re-rendering a reCAPTCHA in the same element container, you have to clear it first by calling `recaptchaVerifier.clear()` and then re-initializing it.

Comment: thanx..but on same  function for "Resend OTP" button not calling https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?key=###### as it works on first button  "Send OTP". how can achive that?